# Recursive SQL Oracle Query for work orders

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, recursive-query

All,

I am trying to create recursive query which has two inputs:

1. ITEM_ID
2. LOT

I have three working subqueries:

1. RECEIVING
2. BATCH
3. INGREDIENT

I found its possible to do so in simple SQL, example of query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE x2 (result) AS ( 
    SELECT 1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT result*2 FROM x2) 
SELECT * FROM x2 LIMIT 10;
```

When I run first subquery **RECEIVING** with 2 inputs *ITEM_ID+LOT* and it returns some rows then its OK and SQL should stop. *If no*, query should start searching in subquery **BATCH** for *BATCH number*, this batch number is used in third subquery **INGREDIENT** which returns *new ITEM_ID+LOT* for **RECEIVING**.

[Diagram for recursive subquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QItly.png)

Example:

INPUT

1. ITEM_ID=1765716
2. LOT=1EP17171590
3. Enter input ITEM_ID (1765716) and LOT (1EP17171590) run first
   subquery **RECEIVING** => no rows returns (if returns, end SQL)
4. Enter input ITEM_ID (1765716) and LOT (1EP17171590) run second subquery 
   **BATCH** => returns BATCH_NO **351908**
5. Enter BATCH_NO (351908) run third subquery **INGREDIENT** => returns new ITEM_ID (1736957) and LOT (1FP17068674) => go to point 3

[Example view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66JBZ.png)

Patrick,

I made this query, its working but its too slow, any idea how to optimalize it?

```
select 
  BATCH_ID,
  BATCH_NO,
  PRODUCT_ITEM_ID,
  PRODUCT_ITEM
  PRODUCT_LOT,
  INGREDIENT_ITEM_ID,
  INGREDIENT_ITEM
  INGREDIENT_LOT,
  LEVEL
FROM
  (
    SELECT 
        b.batch_id,
        b.batch_no,
        b.inventory_item_id as PRODUCT_ITEM_ID,
        b.item as PRODUCT_ITEM,
        b.lot as PRODUCT_LOT,
        i.inventory_item_id AS INGREDIENT_ITEM_ID,
        i.item as INGREDIENT_ITEM,
        i.lot as INGREDIENT_LOT
    FROM batch b
    JOIN ingredients i
    ON i.batch_id = b.batch_id
  )
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR 
    PRODUCT_ITEM_ID = INGREDIENT_ITEM_ID
    AND PRODUCT_LOT = INGREDIENT_LOT
START WITH 
    PRODUCT_ITEM_ID = 1765716 
    AND PRODUCT_LOT = '1EP17171590'
;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide DDL for the tables involved along with sample data as DML and your subqueries.

Comment: Is recursion a requirement for what you are doing? I would reevaluate exactly what you are trying to do and ask that question instead. It sounds like you are trying to treat standard SQL like a typical object-orientated programming language.

Comment: Recursion is not required. I want to get result from RECEIVING table, please see last image to understand the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without recursion like this:

I created tables to use for this using the sample data you provided in the screenshot:

```
create table RECIEVING
(
   ITEM_ID number,
   LOT varchar2(50)
  );

insert into RECIEVING
values(1736957,'1FP17068674');

create table BATCH
(
    BATCH number,
    ITEM_ID number,
    LOT varchar2(50)
  );

insert into BATCH
values(351908,1765716,'1EP17171590');

create table INGREDIENTS
(
  BATCH number,
  ITEM_ID number,
  LOT varchar2(50)
  );

insert into INGREDIENTS
values(351908,1736957,'1FP17068674');
```

This is the query I used:

```
select RECIEVING.ITEM_ID,
       RECIEVING.LOT
from BATCH
join INGREDIENTS
  on BATCH.BATCH = INGREDIENTS.BATCH
join RECIEVING
  on RECIEVING.ITEM_ID = INGREDIENTS.ITEM_ID
 and RECIEVING.LOT = INGREDIENTS.LOT
where BATCH.ITEM_ID = 1765716
  and BATCH.LOT = '1EP17171590';
```

If a batch has multiple ingredients, then it will return more than 1 row back as long as it exists in RECIEVING. I'm not sure if that meets your requirements or not.

The output for the sample you provided looks like this:

```
ITEM_ID     LOT
1736957     1FP17068674
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e987/1)